# how to implement `cvtripleitem` in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

You may know that there exists `cvdoubleitem` in `moderncv` with which you can put double items in one line. Is there a way to self-define a `cvtripleitem` so as to put triple items in one line?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}
\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{aaa}
\cvdoubleitem{xxxx}{aaaaa}{yyyyy}{bbbbb}
% what I want is: \cvtripleitem{xxx}{aaa}{yyy}{bbb}{zzz}{ccc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with a simplification that might be of interest for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}

\newlength\Tripleitemmaincolumnwidth
\newlength\tripleitemmaincolumnwidth

\AtBeginDocument{%
\setlength\tripleitemmaincolumnwidth{% 
  \maincolumnwidth-2\hintscolumnwidth-2\separatorcolumnwidth}%
\setlength\tripleitemmaincolumnwidth{.333333\tripleitemmaincolumnwidth}%   
  }

\newcommand*{\cvtripleitem}[7][.25em]{%
 \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\tripleitemmaincolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}%
   \hfill
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}\raggedleft\hintstyle{#4}\end{minipage}%
   \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\tripleitemmaincolumnwidth}#5\end{minipage}%
   \hfill
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}\raggedleft\hintstyle{#6}\end{minipage}%
   \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\tripleitemmaincolumnwidth}#7\end{minipage}%
   }%
}

\name{John Doe}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\section{Computer skills}
\cvtripleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use `\cvtripleitem` in a similar fashion to `\cvdoubleitem`, but with two additional mandatory arguments (for the third item in the row).

Take into account that, depending on the document page layout, the space reserved for the items might be too narrow.