# How to define horizontal spaces for cvdoubleitem?

Tags: spacing, moderncv

i've found here [how to implement `cvtripleitem` in moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171909/how-to-implement-cvtripleitem-in-moderncv) a way to create a triple item for my CV. Unfortunetaly it goes out of the margins, take a look : [image]

how to correct it ? thanks.

Comment: Can you provide stand-alone code in your question that replicates the problem? That is, don't point us somewhere else to cobble something together, rather keep things self-contained within *this* post. Your code should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allow us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. Remember, keep it minimal, so no extra, unnecessary packages or document elements. Can you do that?